# Must we define methods and async when we don't know whether the implementation is synchronous or asynchronous?

Tags: c#, .net, async

I think I know the answer to this, but it's particular enough that I don't want to go telling other people stuff until I'm 100% certain.

Suppose I have a class with some dependency:

```
public interface IDependency
{
    int DoSomething(string value);
}

public class DependsOnSomething
{
    private readonly IDependency _dependency;

    public DependsOnSomething(IDependency dependency)
    {
        _dependency = dependency;
    }

    public int GetSomeValue(string input)
    {
        return _dependency.DoSomething(input);
    }
}
```

`IDependency` is an abstraction. I haven't yet determined what its implementation will be. I don't know whether it will be CPU-bound or perhaps make some API call.

What's more, the implemenation of `IDependency` could have its own dependencies, and the same could be true of those. They may or may not call async methods.

Would it be correct to say that

- If I consider it likely that something, somewhere will be async, that I should make all of these methods async?
- If nothing in any of the dependencies is async but at some point that changes, and I want to take advantage of that opportunity to free up a thread instead of letting it wait, I would need to go back through all of my methods and make everything `async`?

Generally I can plan for what does or doesn't need to be asynchronous, but I'm trying to understand the potential cost of a) guessing synchronous and b) guessing wrong.

Is my understanding of this correct?

One workaround to the problem might be, in some cases, to define both synchronous and asynchronous methods on interfaces. But that feels wrong because then the interface is describing implementation details, and if the underlying implementation isn't really asynchronous then my interface is lying. (And it could lead to me or someone else writing even more async methods to call something that isn't really async.)

Comment: Why can you not just figure out more of what IDependency is going to do and how it's going to work before building the class using it?

Comment: I'm inclined to agree.  `IDependency` says very little about the operating characteristics of `DoSomething()`.

Comment: The ambiguity of `IDependency` is deliberate. And, since it's an abstraction, I'd rather not have to decide how the implementation is going to work before I create the interface. Making sure that I understand whether or not I must do that is actually at the very heart of my question. My understanding is that we just have to work around that the best we can, which is I suppose is okay since no one has found it to be huge concern.

Comment: Sync or async is not an implementation detail. It is a fundamental design decision. You need to make that decision based on the information you have now (or gather more info first). The price of making the wrong decision is either an overcomplicated design or having to redesign later. I'd go for the latter.

Comment: @ScottHannen: it's virtually impossible to abstract something you know nothing about and end up with an abstraction that improves the situation. Don't be so anxious to just write off "implementation details" because the devil is in the details, and it's not uncommon to discover a little detail that ends up being a significant amount of work to resolve.

Comment: I don't think that whether it's an implementation detail or a fundamental design decision is quite so black and white, either/or. Suppose I have an existing async method that depends on a third-party library. It has no async method so I don't await it. Then they provide an async method, and I await it. To me that's more of an implementation detail than a design decision.

Comment: @ScottHannen: in that scenario, you rarely can just switch async in and out willy nilly without problems. While the .NET Task library does a good job of abstracting syncronization issues away, it doesn't do so perfectly, and you can very easily find deadlocks in async/await code, especially from 3rd party libraries. Async/await is a very high level, fundamental design choice.

Comment: That it's not abstracted away is exactly what I'm trying to clarify. Thanks

Comment: `Task` is not an implementation details, but part of the abstraction contract. Do you want consumer of the abstraction to be able to consume it asynchronously? If yes - use `Task` if not - don't use it.

Comment: I didn't ask this question well because I'm confirming my understanding of the mechanics (accomplished) while asserting conclusions that result from that understanding. In other words, part of my question was a question and the other part is an opinion. I've made it messy.

Comment: Oddly I had moved on when I stumbled across this purely by accident. https://blog.ploeh.dk/2019/02/11/asynchronous-injection/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem, of course, is that in .NET it's "async all the way down," meaning that once you go down the async path, your entire call chain must be async.

So your decision must be *needs-based.*

How do you decide which methods to make async?  A good rule of thumb is the [50ms rule](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/ui-guidelines-for-async.html).  If it is likely that the method is going to take more than 50 milliseconds to execute, make it async.  Microsoft applied this rule to their WinRT platform, and found that about 10 percent of the method calls needed to be async.

This is mostly a UI rule.  If you're talking to a server, the metrics are a bit different.

**Further Reading**
[Should I make a fast operation async if the method is already async?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38118051/102937)

Comment: Just to clarify, what I'm trying to confirm is whether the *interface* must return a `Task` and have its method awaited. And the answer - which is what I was already 90% sure of - is that it depends on the implementation of the interface. It seems a tiny bit odd to have to create the interface around the implementation. The implementation could change. It's a leak. It's a real scenario, but it's manageable (as evidenced by everyone managing it) and the 50ms rule of thumb helps.

Comment: If by that you mean "async is not part of the interface contract," you're right.  Returning a Task in the interface method definition compels the client to deal with the method in an asynchronous way (although not necessarily using the `await` keyword), but the reverse is not true: a method that returns Type T in an interface can still be made asynchronous in the implementation.

Comment: In short, an interface cannot reliably dictate the contract of a method with respect to asynchrony.

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer because the first sentence tells me what I need. As mentioned in other comments I think I added too much "noise" to my question. Thanks.